# Add a new record from subgrid without open a new page

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, dynamics-365

I have an editable subgrid with data from another entity. I can add a new record by a "+" button in a new form page. I need to add that new record, but without a new page opening.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is, enable Quick create for that sub-grid entity and create a Quick create form as well. I believe the parent lookup is already a required field - so this will work like a charm and better UX like a side pop-out form, without navigating away from the current screen. [Read more](https://nakedcrm.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/enabling-quick-create-forms-for-sub-grids-reduce-key-clicks/)

If you are looking for inline row creation in editable grid - its not possible with OOB editable grid. You should develop your own PCF grid or plan to buy Telerik RADgrid kinda stuffs.

Comment: Quick create is already enabled, what customer wants is a "quicker create". I have created a button in the subgrid and I'm working in a js script... but I wondered if there is a better way.

Comment: @MALif you are looking for inline row creation in editable grid - its not possible with OOB editable grid. You should develop your own PCF grid or plan to buy Telerik RADgrid kinda stuffs :(

Comment: @MAL any followup questions ?

Comment: Finally I did a subgrid ribbon button with a javascript fuction (with crm SelectedControl as parameter) that opens a modal with html select inputs to allow users to choose some options. This modal calls to parent.Xrm.WebApi.createRecord and return to main window, which does a subgrid refresh. Surely it was not the best choice, but it is my first step in dynamics and I wanted to be on solid ground (javascript). Thank you so much for your time Arun Vinoth :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Editable Table Custom PCF control. It's adding a new row when you click on a + button.

https://marketplace.bevercrm.com/pcf-controls/46